# Why do commands starting with a space, not show up in bash history?

Tags: bash

In bash, when I use Ctrl-R to retrieve a previous command, why does it not work when the command starts with a whitespace? Can I make it match such a previous command?

```
$  date
Fri Nov 23 ... 2018
(failed reverse-i-search)` date': cd database/
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check the value of your `HISTCONTROL` environment variable. If the value contains `ignorespace` or `ignoreboth`, any command starting with a space will not be added to command history.

From `man bash`:

> HISTCONTROL:
>                 A colon-separated list of values controlling how commands are saved on the history list.  If the list of
>                 values includes ignorespace, lines which begin with a space character are not saved in the history list.
>                 A  value  of  ignoredups  causes  lines matching the previous history entry to not be saved.  A value of
>                 ignoreboth is shorthand for ignorespace and ignoredups.  A value of erasedups causes all previous  lines
>                 matching  the current line to be removed from the history list before that line is saved.  Any value not
>                 in the above list is ignored.  If HISTCONTROL is unset, or does not include a  valid  value,  all  lines
>                 read  by the shell parser are saved on the history list, subject to the value of HISTIGNORE.  The second
>                 and subsequent lines of a multi-line compound command are not tested,  and  are  added  to  the  history
>                 regardless of the value of HISTCONTROL.

Answer (score 2):

That is intended. White space makes no change to the interpretation of the command. History ignores command starting with a space, so that you can enter commands that you don't want logged. It may not be much of a  security mechanism, as someone on the same machine, can spy when you do it.

I think it can be re-configured. See the bash-manual, under history.